# how can I map this using automapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have an Application model in my application:

```
public class Application
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> FunctionIds { get; set; }
}
```

The underlying Application db table has the following structure:

```
Id - string
Name - string
Description - string 
ApplicationFunctions - ApplicationFunctions (FK)
```

I'm currently getting the following error when sending a model without FunctionId's:

```
{"\nUnmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.\nAdd a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type\nFor no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

\nApplication -> Application (Destination member list)\r\nSecurityApi.Core.Models.Application -> 

SecurityApi.EntityFramework.Application (Destination member list)\r\n\r\nUnmapped properties:\r

\nApplicationFunctions\r\n"}
```

What is the proper way to map FunctionIds to ApplicationFunctions? Also is there any special configuration I need to allow a null value for FunctionIds?

Comment: Have you read the docs, specially where it talks about mapping configurations and profiles? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Comment: yes I have the basic top-level mapping done but I'm still not clear on how to implement the id to fk mapping implementation

Comment: Could you post the Application mapping profile?

Comment: @Oscar I'm just doing this:     config.CreateMap<Application, Core.Models.Application>();

Comment: Please show the mapping destination class.

Comment: @ivan - the destination class (Application) is listed in my original post

Comment: Ok, then the source. We really need to see the two classes. being mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Automapper automatically maps members with same name and type, but if they don't match, you must tell Automapper how to do it. First, you create your configuration class:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Application, Core.Models.Application>().ForMember(
        dest => dest.FunctionIds,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ApplicationFunctions);
        //Map other members and classes
    )
  }
}
```

Then, in Global.asax.cs, initialize the configuration:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
}
```

Comment: thanks oscar the code in your answer looks promising but I still get the same error:  ApplicationFunctions is unmapped